# How to join multiple tables in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have below code where I am using entity framework,

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    var query = (from p in db.Products
                     join pd in db.ProductDetails
                         on p.ProductID equals pd.ProductID
                     select new
                     {
                         p.ProductName,
                         pd.IsEnabled
                     }).ToList();

        IEnumerable<Product> products =
            db.Products.Include(x => x.ProductDetail).ToList();

        return products;
}


public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductDetail ProductDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of returning data from only Products table, I want to return data from ProductDetails table as well.

Also, if I want to add where clause here, how would I do that?

I tried Something like this but it doesn't work,

```
public IEnumerable<ProductEnableInfo> GetProducts(int pid) 
{ 
   return db.Products.Select( x => new ProductEnableInfo 
                                 { ProductId = x.ProductID,
                                   ProductName = x.ProductName, 
                                   IsEnabled = x.ProductDetail.IsEnabled 
                                 }).Where(x => x.ProductId == pid) .ToList(); 
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what data you want to query?

Comment: I want ProductName from Products table and IsEnabled from ProductDetails table.

Comment: You are already doing this in the first query

Comment: My include statement returns ProductName but I want to include isEnabled value from another table (ProductDetails).

Comment: your include statement should work also..

Comment: I am not sure I understand the last thing you said. Can you explain?

Comment: Include statement is not returning IsEnabled value.

Comment: it should be.. each product in your list of products should have a `ProductDetail` property and that will have the IsEnabled value.. see answer below

Comment: Note that `.ToList()` ensures you will be requesting the entire Product and ProductDetail table from the DB.  If there is filtering you can pass down to this layer, you should consider doing it, or perhaps return `IQueryable` to delay execution pending row filter criteria.

Comment: How didn't filtering work? Did it throw an exception or did it not return data?

Comment: It does not return correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom class to hold only `ProductName` and `IsEnabled` like this:

```
public class ProductEnableInfo
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can change your method to this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductEnableInfo> GetProducts()
{
    return db.Products.Select(
        x => new ProductEnableInfo
        {
            ProductName = x.ProductName,
            IsEnabled = x.ProductDetail.IsEnabled
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can filter by ProductID like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductEnableInfo> GetProducts(int product_id)
{
    return db.Products
        .Where(x => x.ProductID == product_id)
        .Select(
        x => new ProductEnableInfo
        {
            ProductName = x.ProductName,
            IsEnabled = x.ProductDetail.IsEnabled
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: You can have the `Where` before or after the `Select`. If you do it before, then you have the chance to filter based on any property of `Product`. If you do it after, then you can filter based on `ProductName` or `IsEnabled` only.

Comment: If I return productid as well, how can I filter it out (what would be the where clause)?

Comment: Do you want to include ProductId in the result? Also, do you want to filter based on some ProductId?

Comment: No, I do not want to include ProductId in the result but I want to filter based on ProductId. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `DTO` object and using `Select()` method, you could change the output of the query, for sample:

```
public class ProductDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsEnalbed { get; set; }
}
```

And execute a query like this;

```
IEnumerable<ProductDto> result = db.Products    
                                   .Where(x => x.ProductId == productId) // if you want to filter, just add .Where() method                                   
                                   .Select(x => new ProductDto()
                                          {
                                             Id = x.ProductID,
                                             Name = x.ProductName,
                                             IsEnabled = x.ProductDetail.IsEnabled
                                          })
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: `.Include` is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

this should be giving you what you need.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    IEnumerable<Product> products =
        db.Products.Include(x => x.ProductDetail).ToList();

    return products;
}
```

to access the `IsEnabled` property you just reference the ProductDetail property

```
var products = GetProducts();
foreach (var product in products)
{
    bool enabled = product.ProductDetail.IsEnabled;
}
```